# Is $f^2$ is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-continuity

Let $f$ be uniformly continuous in $I$. Prove or disprove by an example that $f^2$ is uniformly continuous in $I$.

Comment: $f^2=f\circ f$ or $f^2=(f)^2$?

Comment: I meant: $f^2=(f)^2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the well stated comment of @Nilknarf, if $f^2=(f)^2$ then for $I=[0, + \infty)$ and $f(x)=x$ we have the counterxample.

For a proof of this counterexample  we can use the sequential property of uniform continuity by taking the sequences: $$x_n=n + \frac{1}{n}$$ $$y_n=n$$

If the O.P wants the case where $f^2=fof$ then we know that the composition of uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Perhaps this would be better suited as a comment?

Comment: @Nilknarf It's an answer, though.

Comment: @Nilknarf I don't see how. They make an assumption about what the OP means, true, but then supply an actual answer, although not an entirely complete one (which is fine).

Comment: @MathematicsStudent1122 We still don't know what the OP means by $f^2$, and this seems more like a clarification that the OP must mean $f\circ f$ rather than $(f)^2$ than an actual answer to the question.

Comment: I edited..Better now?

Comment: @Marios.When using $ x_n$ and its limit $y_n,$  with $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $ x_n$ converges to a limit, $y_n$, that itself 'runs along the positive real number line', $y_n = n$. Feel a bit more at ease using the equivalent \epsilon, \delta  definitiin to show that $f(x) = x^2$   is not uniformly continuos in $I$. Please comment. Thank you.

Comment: From the definition you can deduce the sequential theorem @PeterSzilas..A function is uniformly continuous  if for every pair od sequences $x_n,y_n$ such that $x_n-y_n \rightarrow 0$ we have $f(x_n)-f(y_n) \rightarrow 0$...So two prove tha a function is not uniformly continuous you just have two fing two sequence where their difference goes to $0$ but the difference of their image doesn't

Comment: Also $x_n-y_n=1/n \rightarrow 0$..i didn't say that $y_n$ is the limit of $x_n$ ..that would be absurd

Comment: @Marios. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you are welcome.